# Exclamation Point

Tags: gramática

Is the following a correct usage of the exclamation point? That is, using the exclamation point in the beginning and at the end of a one word statement:

Welcome - **!Bienvenidos!**

Comment: Due to lazyness, many people (specially in social media) often write *Bienvenidos!* - It's not a terrible thing but it should always have the exclamation sign in the beginning. The same happens for the interrogative sign.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. However, as always, the exclamation point before must be inverted:

> ¡Bienvenidos!